# Does anyone know how to alter magic.mgc file?

Tags: php, unix

Currently, I'm using "file" command to validate files.

however it does not seem to be updated with the latest items extension/mime types.

for example, *.msg files returns with something like 'Composite Document File V2 Document, No summary info'

when what I need is something like "application/vnd.ms-outlook"

Does anyone know any way to fix this? as in, where can I obtain the latest magic.mgc file? or better yet, is there anyway I can add on to the file?

While we're on this topic, what is your technique to validate your files?

Comment: To begin with, you need the `-i` flag (or `--mime`) if you want a  mime type rather than a human readable description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you know what makes the composite documents you have different from every other composite document, you won't be able to fix this.

But if you're still bent on trying to fix this then you'll need to get the [`file` source](ftp://ftp.astron.com/pub/file/) and rebuild the database yourself.

Comment: Damn, that wasn't the answer I was hoping for. Thanks.